# Node.js async.series() don't wait callback to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async.js

My code works when `mongoose.disconnect()` is never called and node program has time to execute all callbacks. When `mongoose.disconnect()` is called at the end of the program and connection is lost those inserts to mongo naturally don't happen.

This async is not waiting for those inserts to complete. Why, and how can I fix it?

mObjectList = array of objects ready for insert

```js
insertMongoObj: function(mObjectList, callback) {
  var tasks = [];

  for (i in mObjectList) {
    tasks.push(mObjectList[i].save());
  }

  async.parallel(tasks, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err, 0);
    }
  });
  callback(null, tasks.length);
}
```

Thank you for your fast reply! Changed function as advised but same thing. Working when connection is never closed and program is never exiting. Mongoose.disconnect() is still closing connection before those inserts.

```js
insertMongoObj : function(mObjectList, callback){

    var tasks = [];

    for (i in mObjectList) {
      tasks.push(mObjectList[i].save.bind(mObjectList[i]));
    }

    async.parallel(tasks, function(err) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        winston.info("  file processing ready");
    });

    return callback();
}
```

---

The previous function calls are here:

```
mongoose.connection.once('open', function () {
    talendToMongo.processTalendExport(objPaths, function(){
        mongoose.disconnect();
    });

});

processTalendExport : function(talendEntityLocationList, callback){
    var mongoObjectList = [];
    var self = this;
    for(obj in talendEntityLocationList){
        winston.info("**Start processing directory:" + talendEntityLocationList[obj]);
        var fileList = fs.readdirSync(talendEntityLocationList[obj]);
        this.processEntityDir(talendEntityLocationList[obj], fileList, function(mongoObjectList){
            self.insertMongoObj(mongoObjectList, function(err){
                if(err) {
                    winston.error("  Error processing file:" + talendEntityLocationList[obj]);
                        process.exit(0);
                    } else {
                        winston.info(" Mongo Objects inserted");
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        callback();
    }

insertMongoObj : function(mObjectList, callback){
    var tasks = [];

    for (i in mObjectList) {
        tasks.push(mObjectList[i].save.bind(mObjectList[i]));
    }

    async.parallel(tasks, function(err) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
          winston.info("  file processing ready");
        });

        return callback();
    }
```

Comment: Thus the async...You are not waiting for the tasks to finish, you have 2 choices, the obvious one is what Dan provided, and the 2nd is to use some sort of counter to track competed tasks...You're probably don't wanna do it that way.

Comment: Just a small suggestion; don't pass zero to the callback when you have an error executing the tasks. Pass only the error object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the last callback invocation into the callback for `async.parallel`:

```
for (i in mObjectList) {
  tasks.push(mObjectList[i].save.bind(mObjectList[i]));
}

async.parallel(tasks, function(err) {
     if (err) {
         return callback(err, 0);
     }
     return callback(null, tasks.length);
 });
```

Comment: Still calling callback twice in error case.  Also `mObjectList[i].save()` is executing before its added to task list.  SHould be `tasks.push(mObjectList[i].save)`.

Comment: @BenTaber: He's using `return` to avoid calling the callback twice. If you don't like that style then use the more obvious `else`

Answer (score 0):

This is a great case where `async.each` is ideal.

```
insertMongoObj: function(mObjectList, callback) {
    async.each(mObjectList, function(obj, done){
        obj.save(done);
    }, callback);
}
```

#### Update

In `processTalendExport`, you have `callback()` after the `for(obj in talendEntityLocationList){` loop instead of after the insertions are done, so it will call `.disconnect` before the insertions have had time to finish. Depending on the client, and the network, that could always cause failures, or only fail sometimes. You should be using `async.each(talendEntityLocationList, ...` to look over that list too.

Comment: Thank you! Tested also this one, but same thing. When disconnect() is called nothing is inserted in Mongo. Without closing connection all the documents are inserted.....

Comment: Are you calling `disconnect` inside of `callback`? I'd need to see the code that calls `insertMongoObj` to say more.

Comment: Added the calls you requested. Thanks for helping. This is not show stopper for me, but just annoying when something is not going as planned....

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working correcting previous function callbacks and fixing async.eachSeries callbacks:

```
    insertMongoObjects : function(mongoObjList, callback){
        var insertCnt = 0;
        winston.info("    Start mongo object insert");
        async.eachSeries(mongoObjList,
            function(mongoObj, done){
                    mongoObj.save(function(save_result){
                        if(!save_result){ 
                            insertCnt++
                            done(null);
                        } else { done(save_result); }
                    });
            },
            function(err){
                if(err) {
                    winston.error("    Error inserting mongo object:");
                    winston.error(err);
                    callback(err);
                } else {
                    winston.info("    Mongo object insert successful for:" + insertCnt);
                    callback();
                }
            }
        );
    }
```